# Why i can't use v-skeleton-loader with vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-suspense

i don't know why i cant use v-skeleton-loader. anytime i use the component the console throw me this warning : Failed to resolve component: v-skeleton-loader.

i use vuetify": 3.1.4

```
<Suspense>
          <template #default>
            <boutique_data />
          </template>
          <template #fallback>
            <v-sheet class="px-3 pt-3 pb-3">
              <v-skeleton-loader type="table" :loading="true"></v-skeleton-loader>
            </v-sheet>
          </template>

</Suspense>
```

when i remove the component and i put some random stuff inside my fallback template , everything works fine.
i hope somebody can help me

thanks in advance

Comment: I take it you've come from a vuetify version 2 project since you know about skeleton loader - I believe the skeleton loader hasn't been converted to version 3 yet - the big clue to that is that it is not documented at all in vuetify version 3 documentation.

Comment: indeed there is nothing on the documentation of vuetify 3, on the other hand on the chinese documentation of vuetify we can find it
https://vuetify.cn/en/components/skeleton-loaders/

Comment: 2.3.1 was released in June 2020 (the version of that documentation) so the chinee documentation is 2 and a half years out of date

Comment: Vuetify 3 is not yet production ready (and has some breaking changes). You may consider switching to Quasar 2 - it is fully compatible with Vue 3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

v-skeleton-loader is available for [v3.1.13+](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/releases/tag/v3.1.13) and we should import it from [Labs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/labs/introduction/).

Answer (score 0):

The skeleton loader is available in the v3.4.0 (Blackguard) version.

Comment: I have it at 3.3, just need to import and inject it to `createVuetify` components (`import * as VSkeletonLoader from 'vuetify/labs/VSkeletonLoader'; createVuetify({components: { ...VSkeletonLoader }});`